# "client_id rejected" error when retrieving the access_token

Tags: support, authentication, oauth2

I'm developing an application in C# and I to post questions, so I need an access token.

I registered my application and I have received a client ID. Then I get the following query-string to get the access token:

https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=3996&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success

> The following error occurs (¿on page redirection?):
>
> Application Login Failure
>
> An error occurred while login into an application. Error Details
>
> error description: client_id rejected

What is the reason for the error? How I could resolve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that you've used an invalid id or that the settings on your app page are incorrect.

Do the following:

1. Go to [*Your Apps* page](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/).  You should see your app listed.  If it is not, then [register a new app](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register).
2. Click on your app's settings page. For example: [stackapps.com/apps/oauth/view/3996](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/view/3996).  Note that only the owner can see a given app's settings page.
3. For [the kind of authorization](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) you seem to be attempting, make your settings as follows:

   1. **Stack Apps Post** must be set to a valid post that you own.
      In this case, `https://stackapps.com/questions/5017/` should work for *user2621858*.
   2. **Enable Client Side OAuth Flow** ==> checked
   3. **Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri** ==> not checked
   4. **OAuth Domain** ==> `stackexchange.com`
   5. **Application Name** ==> (not blank and no error message)
   6. **Description** ==> (not blank and no error message)
   7. **Application Website** ==> `http://localhost/foo/` (Not critical for this kind of auth.)

---

Finally, be sure that your app hasn't been disabled for gross attempts at violating quota limits or terms of service or ignoring the `backoff` flag. (I'm not sure what the error message would be for a banned app and that is probably not the case for this OP at this time.)